# How to process each row in file1, while comparing the processed row's md5 hash from file2 to avoid duplicates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, stream, node.js-fs

I have a manifest, `file1`. I can't guarantee there wont be dupes and it's unsorted.
I want to process each row, skipping dupes. What's the best way to do this?

file1.txt

```
foo
alice
bar
baz
alice
bob
```

file2

```
"5795d4c18d8c15bd14acf4ce782af4be": "foo"
"dc26468e231eb1877cbd9dc5959da9e4": "alice"
"6b4f37e79bf1329a61704ce55d674507": "bar"
"36b9f08cfbbc368cf6f5f6cf78871140": "baz"
```

Alice shouldn't be processed twice here since that row was already encountered previously.

Right now my thought process is to write the md5 hash to a separate file (`file2`), and do
a lookup, but am unsure about how to do this lookup efficiently since `file2` is constantly being written to.

I'd prefer not to store the dictionary in memory. What's the most efficient way
to perform the hash lookup from `file2` without reading the whole file into memory? Is there a way to do the lookup in `O(1)`?

I'm using streams right now to read the files.

```js
const reader = readline.createInterface(filestream);
  reader.on('line', (line) => {
    // Checksum val to de-dupe if there's the same path multiple times in the
    // manifest.
    const hash = crypto.createHash('md5')
      .update(line)
      .digest("hex");

    // TODO: what to do here? Stream from file2 feels wrong/inefficient.
    // if hash exists in file2
    //   continue

    if (Processor.normalizeFile(line)) {
      fs.writeFile('./file2', `${hash}: ${line}`);
    }
  });
```

Comment: "What's the most efficient way to perform the hash lookup from file2 without reading the whole file into memory?" - Use a database.  Put file2 into a simple database.  That's what a database is specifically designed to do (fast lookups without all the data in memory).  Otherwise, there is no super efficient way to look up a key in file2 without holding at least the lookup keys in memory.

Comment: Fair enough. I was hoping I could avoid using a db, but it is what it is. Thanks!

Comment: If you know the practical size limits of file2, you could decide if reading the file once into memory into an appropriate memory data structure was practical or not given the system you're running it on.  There are also in-memory databases like redis which use memory outside of the nodejs process.  But, if you persistently need to do lookups in the file1 data or it can be super large, then putting it into a local database once and using the data from there is probably best.

Comment: FYI, `fs.writeFile('./file2', `${hash}: ${line}`);` in your existing code will overwrite the previous file so I presume that is not what you want.  Perhaps you want `fs.appendFile()`?  And, you will have to make sure you wait until this operation is done before trying to write the next line.